# System Interrupts are killing my Laptop

Tags: linux, windows, boot, hardware-failure, interrupts

I have a Dell XPS 15 Laptop which had started overheating and shutting down. I had opened it up to clean it, which stopped the overheating. and after putting it back, *2 USB ports didn't work properly* (they don't detect the device plugged in, but **sometimes** supply power to it)

1. When my computer starts, **sometimes** after choosing the OS from the boot menu (Linux/Windows dual-boot), the system hangs. I have to reboot after this (sometimes multiple times) to get to a my OS.
2. **Sometimes**, after starting the OS, things work just fine for some random amount of time, and then system starts **stuttering** and comes to a halt a little time after that.

I've looked at the Performance Monitor logs and linux's top, and it shows a **System Interrupts** process eating about 98% of CPU before the system dies. I also disabled linux's Plymouth to actually see system output while booting up and shutting down. There I sometimes get this output (and the system indeed fails to shut down)

```
   [..timestamp..] hub 3-0:1.0: hub_port_status failed (err = -19)
   [..timestamp..] hub 3-0:1.0: hub_port_status failed (err = -19)
   .
   .
   [..timestamp..] hub 4-0:1.0: hub_port_status failed (err = -19)
   [..timestamp..] hub 4-0:1.0: hub_port_status failed (err = -19)


   [..timestamp..] hub 4-0:1.0: hub_port_status failed (err = -19)
```

Points I need help on:

1. Are my USB ports causing the interrupts? (I'm checking this now... I'll update the status)
2. **Is there a way to further diagnose this interrupts issue? (tools)**
3. Would plugging out the ports from the motherboard stop the interrupts (checking this too)
4. Is there a way to fix this (without replacing the WHOLE board)?

Thanks, and looking hopefully to some answers/pointers.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you diagnose a hardware problem after opening a machine, you should power the machine down until the problem can be located and corrected. Most likely, some internal connector for those USB ports was connected incorrectly. Perhaps it wasn't lined up correctly, perhaps it wasn't pushed all the way in, the possible problems depend on the type of connector used. It's also possible some foreign metal object got into the case and is causing a short. You need to check carefully.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would disconnecting the USB connector from the motherboard stop the interrupts?

Comment: @Harsh It's hard to be sure without trying. It depends exactly what the problem is.